# Django: why is ViewClass.as_view used with brackets in URLconf?

Tags: django

If I have a view-class and I want to use it in URLconf, I will have to use its `as_view()`-method, since the view-class isn't a function, but a class. My question is, in URLconf, why is `as_view()` called with brackets? Doesn't this mean that the function will be run upon reading URLconf? If so, what is it exactly that `as_view` does?

Example:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from some_app.views import AboutView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/$', AboutView.as_view()), # <--- We're calling the method. Why?
]
```

Comment: You can have a look what it does here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L48

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all views that people create in Class Based Views are subclasses of the core Django CBVs.  That means that you inherit the `as_view` method, as you've pointed out above.  Why do we need that?  It's just below the section in docs that declares the CBV I believe you've taken as an example for your question:

```
# some_app/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "about.html"
```

So in the `urls.py`, you could reference this - except the Django urls dispatcher [is looking for a callable function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher) (after 1.10).

> Because Django’s URL resolver expects to send the request and
>   associated arguments to a callable function, not a class, class-based
>   views have an as_view() class method which returns a function that can
>   be called when a request arrives for a URL matching the associated
>   pattern.

Each subclassed view inherits the `as_view` method which provides this, being called at URL delcaration time.  This returns a function, which can be used at request time (per Daniel's comment below.)

And from the `as_view` [section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view):

> When the view is called during the request/response cycle, the
>   HttpRequest is assigned to the view’s request attribute. Any
>   positional and/or keyword arguments captured from the URL pattern are
>   assigned to the args and kwargs attributes, respectively. Then
>   dispatch() is called.

This makes it function in the same way as the longer-winded FBV, which takes in a request, does *stuff* and then returns an HttpResponse:

```
def some_view(request): 
    pass #do some stuff 
    context = { "foo": "bar"}
    return render(request, 'about.html', context)
```

Comment: Sorry, your description of what the as_view method does is inaccurate. The method itself is not called during the request cycle, but at URL declaration time. It returns a function, which at request time in turn instantiates the class and calls is dispatch method.

Comment: And note, a class *is* callable; it would be perfectly possible to pass one to the URL dispatcher. The reason why that doesn't happen is it would encourage thread-unsafe behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, have edited re: the first part, and cleared up sloppy language re the second.